# replace one of the elements in a jQuery non-DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

```
html = "<p>title</p><div><ul class='www'></ul>something</div>";
$html = $(html);
$html.filter('p').replaceWith('<h2>' + $html.filter('p').html() + '</h2>'); //not working 
container = $('<div></div>');
html = container.html($html)[0].innerHTML; //trying to output "<h2>title</h2><div><ul class='www'></ul>something</div>"
```

In a non-DOM environment, I am trying to modify an HTML string, replacing one of its members. jQuery's `replaceWith` doesn't work because it is meant for DOM. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example. First I remove B and then prepend it to A. Afterwards I insert a new C. You can substitute A, B and C with everything.

Important is, that you remove and append/prepend it manuallay :)

```js
a = $('#a');
b = $('#b');
c = $('<span>').attr('id', 'c').text('C');

b.remove();
a.prepend(b);
a.append(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <span id="a">A</span>
  <span id="b">B</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the element is replaced, the `$html` is not updated as `p` is in the root of the `$html` variable

```js
html = "<p>title</p><div><ul class='www'></ul>something</div>";
$container = $('<div></div>');
$container.html(html);
$container.find('p').replaceWith(function(idx, html) {
  return '<h2>' + html + '</h2>'
})
html = $container[0].innerHTML;
console.log(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```